# How to resize one dimensional array VBA using Redim

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to resize a dynamic array (`Sub rangearray`) with new values after checking if any values in the original array > 590.
The array is one dimensional column with a range of figures as shown below just 1 column and multiples rows.

I have tried a variety of possible solutions and none seems to work. I can observe on the Locals window even though this is a one dimensional array it appears a two dimensional with `(1 to 5, 1 to 1)` and I did manage to obtain 620 and 630 on the message box and I tried to replicate this code for the worksheet but I constantly got subscript out of range.

I would appreciate if someone could please let me know what I need to do to resize the array (copied to sheet) with only the new values not the previous values and also explain the dimension of one dimension and multiples dimensions array.
I do know that with `Redim` you can only change the second dimension and that is where I am a bit confused does the one dimension below have two dimension or one its seems like two otherwise it would only have one dimension which should make resizing easier.

Solution that works but just message box not worksheet

```vb
For i = 1 To 5
    For j = 1 To 1
        If arr(i, j) > 590 Then
            MsgBox arr(i, j)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Dataset

```
590
590
590
620
630
```

Array that does not work below paste value from resized array to worksheet

```vb
Sub rangearray()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim ws2 As Workbook

    Set ws2 = Workbooks("PRA.XLSM")
    Set ws = Workbooks("PRA.XLSM").Worksheets("Rec")
    Set ws1 = Workbooks("PRA.XLSM").Worksheets("CPT")

    arr() = ws.Range("a4:a15").Value

    For Each i In arr
        If i > 590 Then
            ReDim arr(i)
            arr(i) = i
        End If
    Next i

    ws1.Range("A4:A15").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your array to be processed is a 2D array type. You do not need (only) an 1D array to accomplish what you want, but if this is your wish, it can be done using another array (1D in this case, but it could be 2D, too).
2. `Redim` can be used for any `Dim` array without specifying the dimensions. `Redim Preserve` can be used only for the second dimension and it means changing the second one, but preserving values.
3. Please, use this code to accomplish what (I understood) you wanted:

```
    Dim arr() As Variant, ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, i As Long
    Dim arrF As Variant, k As Long
    
    Set ws = Workbooks("PRA.XLSM").Worksheets("Rec")
    Set ws1 = Workbooks("PRA.XLSM").Worksheets("CPT")

    arr() = ws.Range("a4:a15").Value
    ReDim arrF(UBound(arr))

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) < 590 Then
            arrF(k) = arr(i, 1): k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve arrF(k - 1)
    ws1.Range("A4").Resize(UBound(arrF) + 1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrF)
End Sub
```

4. What I think it is good to know, you could also use a 2D (new) array. In such a case you had to `Redim` in this way:

```
ReDim arrF(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arr))' the rows and columns are reversed, only to allow Redim Preserve (for the last dimension), after the loop where it was load
```

It should be load (like a 2D array)  in this way:

```
arrF(1, k) = arr(i, 1)
```

And `Resize` should be adapted to a 2D array:

```
ws1.Range("A4").Resize(UBound(arrF, 2), 1).Value
```

`Transpose` is maintained but only to transpose rows to columns...

Answer (score 1):

- First of all when you copy the values of a a range (multi-cell) into a `Variant`, you will always get a two-dimensional array. For example

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Range("A1:A5")
```

means that `arr` is a two dimensional array similar to `arr(1 to 5, 1 to 1)` (i.e. 5 rows and 1 column)

- If you want to get a one-dimensional array you can use the `Transpose` worksheet function

```
Dim arr as Variant
arr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A1:A5"))
```

Now it is like `arr(1 to 5)`

I am confused as to what you're doing in the loop. For example when you find a value of `i > 590` (e.g. 600) you are re-dimensioning the array to 600 elements. Is that what you want? Furthermore, you are not perserving any values. `For each i in arr` gives `i` values of the elements of your arry (not the index), so doing something like `arr(i) = i` is assining the value of `i` to the `i`th element (is this what you're trying to achieve?)

I get the impression, all you want is to change values of those elements `> 590` and for that you do not need to `Redim`: You simply change the value.

If you can explain exactly what you're trying to achieve, then I (or someone else) can help you further.

**Edit (Answer)**:

Here are two of many ways you can achieve what you want:

1. The simplest way is to use the `Filter()` worksheet function. In your destination range enter the array formula

```
=FILTER(Rec!$A$4:$A$15,Rec!$A$4:$A$15>590)
```

1. Build an array to store the filtered values (I guess this is the approach you prefer)

```
Sub rangearray()
    Dim vInput As Variant
    Dim arrOutput() As Variant
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim lOutElems As Long:  lOutElems = 0
    Dim wb As Workbook:     Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbooks("PRA.XLSM")
    Dim ws As Worksheet:    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Rec")
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet:   Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("CPT")
    
    vInput = ws.Range(ws.Range("A4"), ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)).Value
    'vInput = ws.Range("a4:a15").Value ' or hardcoded
    
    For Each v In vInput
        If v > 590 Then
            lOutElems = lOutElems + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrOutput(1 To lOutElems)
            arrOutput(lOutElems) = v
        End If
    Next v

    ws1.Range("A4").Resize(lOutElems, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrOutput)
End Sub
```

- Another approach is to use autofilter (in excel sheet or in VBA). You could also use the `Filter()` worksheet function in VBA. The choice is yours.

Comment: Thank you for your partial answer and sorry for the confusion .You are right I am trying to  paste those values in the array which are >590 on the worksheet.Yes I need to get the index showing the values of i and not i values.

Comment: You provided a sample dataset in your post. Could you please provide your desired output as well.

Comment: Be aware that `Worksheetfunction.Transpose` will not work as expected if the are more than `2^16` elements. And, even more disturbing, there is no error returned.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for this, I wasn't aware of that :) In reality I don't think the OP needs to redim any array, but it is really difficult for me to understand exactly what needs done (I guess it is only me since there are other answers)

Comment: my desired output is for the sheet where i am copying the filtered data to show just values > 590  thus  620 and 630 .I want to filter the original array and just copy values greater that 590 to my specified spreadsheet .

Comment: Thank you Super Symmetry for your partial answer it was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Declare a new variable named `value` (1-dimensional array), after check condition, use `redim preserve` combination with `worksheetfunction.transpose` will work:

Here's sample code:

```
Sub rangearray()
Dim value()
ReDim value(1 To 15 - 4 + 1)
arr = Range("a4:a15").value
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
    For Each cell In arr
         If cell > 590 Then
            value(i) = cell
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
 ReDim Preserve value(1 To i - 1)
 Range("A4:A15").Clear 'clear contents before write new values
 Range("A4:A15").Resize(i - 1, 1).value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dang ,Thank you for your solution I can confirm that it works .It only shows the 620 and 630 which is exactly what I wanted .Please can you explain what the redim value (-4+1) is it creating a new variable as said above  and also Redim preserve (1 to 1 -1) is saving the new figures i presume.Its the indexation which I am  trying to understand.

Comment: Hi John Tomasson, if you declare `dim value(1 to x)` then you can't redim it. let declare variable without upperbound then redim with specify length `ex: 15-4+1 is total cell in the range` . after check condition, you can see `i=i+1` , so exactly only i-1 elements are created. Just `redim preserve to get first i-1 element` in value and that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub rangearray()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim a() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws2 As Workbook
    Dim n As Long

    Set ws2 = Workbooks("PRA.XLSM")
    Set ws = Workbooks("PRA.XLSM").Worksheets("Rec")
    Set ws1 = Workbooks("PRA.XLSM").Worksheets("CPT")

    arr() = ws.Range("a4:a15").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i, 1) > 590 Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve a(1 To n)
            a(n) = i
            'a(n) = i + 3 'If you need the cell's row number,
        End If
    Next i

    ws1.Range("A4").Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(a)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Dy.Lee your solution only shows the index position of 620 and 630 not the actual values

Comment: @JohnTomasson, if you want value  then `a(n) = arr(i,1)`

Comment: @ Dy.Lee I can confirm that your solution works as well Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can read single column values into a 1D array using `WorksheetFunction.Transpose` twice. For example, you have a column with data starting in A1 cell. Then you can fill the 1D array as follows:

```
Sub ch()
 Dim arr()
 Dim nRows As Integer
 nRows = Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
 ReDim arr(1 To nRows)
 arr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(nRows, 1)))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Fane Duru I can confirm that your solution works as well and it copies the data on the new sheet as I wanted whilst keeping the original data set intact.